# Cannot parse CDATA with SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml, libxml2

I have the following XML code:

```
<para>
      <![CDATA[
        <?php
        $data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <root>content</root>';
        $sxe = simplexml_load_string($data);
        var_dump($sxe);
        ?>
      ]]>
    </para>
```

I want to parse the CDATA section to take this result:

```
Content:
<?php
$data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>content</root>';
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($data);
var_dump($sxe);
?>
```

I use the following but it doesn't work.

```
$xml='sxml.xml';
$book = simplexml_load_file($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$para = $book->chapter->para[1];
print "Content: ".$para."<br>";

foreach($para AS $node) {
    print "Iter Content: ".$node."<br>";    
}
```

This results in:

```
Content: 


        content';
        $sxe = simplexml_load_string($data);
        var_dump($sxe);
        ?>
```

In phpinfo() it shows that libxml is enabled and active.
Any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode the special characters using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

For example:
`print "Content: ".htmlspecialchars($para)."<br>";`

Comment: Can you give me an example if you can?

Comment: @MrGlass means to say that the node content is being echoed as requested, but because you are viewing it in a browser, the nodes are parsed as HTML, which do not resolve to anything, as they are not valid HTML tags. View the source to see them, or escape your output with `htmlspecialchars`.