# SimpleXML can't get CDATA with ns prefixes

Tags: php, xml, cdata, xenforo

I've been struggling  to get CDATA from an xml file for the past few hours, even though I've tried different methods shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970602/php-how-to-handle-cdata-with-simplexmlelement), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527447/cannot-parse-cdata-with-simplexml), and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php#84365).

My dilemma has to do with retrieving thread data through xenForo's RSS feeds. Here is a sample of the RSS data I'm trying to retrieve, everything works fine except for retrieving the `<content:encoded>`.

Sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
  <channel>
    <title>News &amp; Announcements</title>
    <description>All of our important news and announcements will be here.</description>
    <pubDate>Fri, 26 Jun 2015 14:54:20 +0000</pubDate>
    <lastBuildDate>Fri, 26 Jun 2015 14:54:20 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <generator>********* ****</generator>
    <link>https://***.****.****/forum/news/</link>
    <atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="https://***.****.****/forum/news/index.rss"/>
    <item>
      <title>Site under development.</title>
      <pubDate>Thu, 25 Jun 2015 05:49:43 +0000</pubDate>
      <link>https://***.****.****/threads/site-under-development.3/</link>
      <guid>https://***.****.****/threads/site-under-development.3/</guid>
      <author>invalid@example.com (*****)</author>
      <dc:creator>ShortCut Central</dc:creator>
      <content:encoded><![CDATA[Content to retrieve. <br /> Some more content a part of the same section]]></content:encoded>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

My current code looks like

```
<?php
class SCC_Main_miscFuncs {
    public static function printMostRecentPost() {
        // Re-enable the below once we're ready to release
        //$rssUrl = func_get_arg(1);
        $rssUrl = 'https://www.shortcutcentral.org/indev.rss';
        $xml = simplexml_load_string(self::returnContents($rssUrl));
        $rawData = self::returnContents($rssUrl); // Properly contains the CDATA
        echo '<pre>';
        //echo (string) $xml->channel->item->encoded;
        //echo (string) $xml->channel->item->content;
        //var_dump($xml);
        echo '</pre>';
        //echo (string) $xml->channel->item;
        //echo $array[@attributes]['item']['link'];
        //echo $xml->message;
    }

    public static function returnContents($url){
        $curl_handle=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'ShortCut Central');
        $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to show the said CDATA except for the unparsed $rawData. I feel it might be because I'm not calling it properly (being completely new to XML and namespaces and namespace prefixes), but it not showing up through var_dump is giving me... hell. I saw some earlier posts about using XML children, but I don't entirely understand that concept, which is why, if my solution requires XML children, an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Also might be worth mentioning that my php code is organized in the way that it is (classes and public, static functions) so that I can use it as an add-on for xenForo.

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: @GordonM Is the link to the sample not working for you? (Click on sample, above)

Comment: @Adam you are supposed to include all relevant code as **a valid minimum example**. External sites may change, links get broken, then your question won't make sense any more in the future, if someone wants to learn from your question and its answers

Comment: @Michi I will include it, but I have seen people bashed on for including walls of code in their post in the past, so....

Comment: @Adam well done, valid minimum example is key, no wall of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that one method to return the namespaced node in SimpleXML is to use [`SimpleXMLElement::children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) but you must pass the namespace as its first argument. You may pass the full namespace string `"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"`, but it is easier to pass its prefix `"content"`, and also then supply `TRUE` as the second argument to inform `children()` that you are passing a prefix rather than the full string.

So using an expression on your `$xml` object like:

```
echo (string)$xml->channel->item->children('content', TRUE)->encoded;
// Prints:
// Content to retrieve. <br /> Some more content a part of the same section
```

Use whatever method makes the most sense in context of your code to retrieve all the relevant nodes in a loop.

Retrieving attributes from namespaced nodes isn't much different. To get the `<atom:link href>` for example:

```
echo (string)$xml->channel->children('atom', true)->link->attributes()['href'];
// Prints
// https://***.****.****/forum/news/index.rss
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this later today and mark your answer as the working one once I'm done.